# Getting Full AST in V8, Lazy Compilation Issue

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, static-analysis, v8, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to get full AST ( Abstract Syntax Tree ) of a javascript code and I have decided to use V8's parser. After trying to use V8, what I realize is that V8 does not parse functions which are not executed ( dead code ). My assumption is V8 is triggering the parsing of function only when it is about to get executed. I think it calls it Lazy compilation

Is there any way to get the full AST from within V8, even for those function which have no chance of getting executed ? Is there any flag setting that I can do to force V8 to generate the full AST ?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against this idea -- see my [reply](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/v8-users/ast%2420rossberg/v8-users/_WracRX9BTQ/vON21HDOshEJ) to a similar question on the V8-users list. Lazy parsing is yet another issue in addition to the ones I point out there, and although V8 has a few knobs to make certain functions parse eagerly, it is far from trivial to get this to work in general.

Comment: Any hints on the non trivial part of turning the "complex" knobs, you would like to share

Comment: You have to turn more than knobs for the general case, you really need to hack. There is no easy recipe I can share. You'll run into very subtle implicit assumptions in various parts of the system that can take days to work out, even if you are familiar with the system. The V8 parser is in no way designed to be used in isolation, and quite intermingled with other parts of the system.

Comment: Logically it seems CompileLazy should get triggered when execution encounters a function which has not been parsed yet. I tried running the debugger and analyze the stack but I think there is some memory address trickery which is at work. Atleast few lines of description would be encouraging to understand V8 theory though it may not lead me to get a full AST